# Cannot add "Public" area in mvc4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, area

My issue is simple. When I try to add a `Public` area in my MVC4 project, the name of this area is replaced by `_Public`. Does anybody knows why? I haven't found anything on the MVC4 release note about that.

It worked just fine for MVC3 projects.

Edit: screeshots

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can only imagine that it has something to do with `public` being a reserved word. I don't doubt it worked fine in MVC3, however there were probably some bug reports somewhere and they ended up protecting you from yourself.

Comment: Yes it probably is a reserved word but what I am interested in is to know why. I checked on MSDN and Google and found nothing about it.

Comment: @Florent - maybe focus your searching on connect? There's potentially a conversation out there on it.